# Arduino components

Tags: components

I’m teaching and learning coding with MicroBit and was wondering if these components are compatible with MicroBit. The specific kits labeled for MicroBit are twice the price but the components look similar. Just trying to save a few bucks. Would [this kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0721B8228) work with my MicroBit?

Comment: That is a whole collection of components, most of them simple electronic components not specific for Arduino. Some components are more complex, but they also should work with the microbit. This is seen from the first glance, I didn't looked into everything in detail. What can be done simultaneously on the microbit depends more on what you try to build. What components did you see, that where marked compatible with Microbit? It might be easier to point out devices, that are microbit specific instead of the one which are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the MicroBit runs on 3.3V versus 5V for most Arduino boards. You'd need to use 3.3V components.

It looks like the kit you linked to is built for (and includes) a 5V Arduino, so those accessories would not work with your MicroBit.

There are other Arduino boards that run on 3.3V. Look for 3.3v accessories. Those should work.

### EDIT:

---

I assume that the MicroBit is capable of I2C interfacing. If so, you should look at the SparkFun Qwiic system. It's a setup with 3.3V I2C serial interface in a 4-wire ribbon cable with a standard connector. You can easily daisy-chain Qwiic devices by just plugging Qwiic cables between them, and they are reasonably priced. I bought some of them thinking I could use them with my Arduino projects, only to discover that they use 3.3V, so I can't use them without I2C voltage translation interfaces, which makes them much less appealing.

Comment: Thanks. For speedy response

Comment: See the edit to my answer, talking about SparkFun Qwicc devices.